# How can I create category page for product listing?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-list, category-page

Can anyone help me for create page for showing products in one or some category in **magento 2.3.1** .

Comment: Have u checked at admin?

Comment: yes , i have created Category for my products and also it shows products that included this Category in admin panel but i can not see this page in frontend . it says **WHOOPS, OUR BAD...**

Comment: Have you tried to reindex after the changes. Please check your indexer status